# What permissions does the service account need to use database mail?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, database-mail

I have an SQL Server 2012 instance running under a managed service account. I've configured database mail with one account and am trying to send a test email, but I'm getting some errors in the server's event logs:

> Database Engine Instance=MYINSTANCE;Mail PID=2132;Error Message:The update to the database failed. Reason: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sysmail_logmailevent_sp', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
>
> Database Engine Instance=MYINSTANCE;Mail PID=2212;
> Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException
> Message: The read on the database failed. Reason: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_readrequest', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
> Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
> TargetSite: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Objects.QueueItem GetQueueItemFromCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
> HelpLink: NULL
> Source: DatabaseMailEngine

If I make the account running the SQL Server process a sysadmin, this error goes away, and mails send successfully. However, all the research I've done suggests that giving this account the `DatabaseMailUserRole` role in the `msdb` database should be sufficient. I've done this and still receive the same errors.

I took a look in the BOL but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is sql server and sql agent running under the same account ?

Comment: @kin No, separate accounts (both managed service accounts).

Comment: can you try to run SQL Agent with the same service account as sql server - just to rule it out and check if that works ?

Comment: @Kin That has sysadmin permission, so it will work. I've given my main service account sysadmin permission for now and everything is working - I'm just curious to know if that's too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server Agent service account requires sysadmin permissions on the instance.

[Microsoft KB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx)